# not able to use parseInt as a onTrue or onFalse function for ifElse of ramdajs

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I use ifElse of ramdajs to read query parameter as below.

```
const page = ifElse(
  identity,
  Number.parseInt,
  always(1)
)(this.ctx.request.query.page);
```

It didn't work. page is logged as a function.
However, I did find a way to let it work. I wrapped parseInt as a normal function as

```
const page = ifElse(
  identity,
  (s) => Number.parseInt(s),
  always(1)
)(this.ctx.request.query.page);
```

Then it worked.
Aren't they the same?

This is the result of ramdajs repl: [repl result](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.25.0#?console.log%28ifElse%28%0A%20%20identity%2C%0A%20%20%28s%29%20%3D%3E%20Number.parseInt%28s%29%2C%0A%20%20always%281%29%0A%29%28%2733%27%29%29%3B%0A%0A%0Aconsole.log%28ifElse%28%0A%20%20identity%2C%0A%20%20Number.parseInt%2C%0A%20%20always%281%29%0A%29%28%2733%27%29%29%3B%0A)

Comment: *It didn't work. page is logged as a function* So, the condition gives a different result altogether?

Comment: Can you replicate your issue here http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.25.0 and share the URL?

Comment: I think the condition doesn't change. The only difference is how I wrote the OnTrue function.

Comment: http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.25.0#?console.log%28ifElse%28%0A%20%20identity%2C%0A%20%20%28s%29%20%3D%3E%20Number.parseInt%28s%29%2C%0A%20%20always%281%29%0A%29%28%2733%27%29%29%3B%0A%0A%0Aconsole.log%28ifElse%28%0A%20%20identity%2C%0A%20%20Number.parseInt%2C%0A%20%20always%281%29%0A%29%28%2733%27%29%29%3B%0A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then it worked. Aren't they the same?

No, There are two differences

1. `Number.parseInt` expects two arguments hence has arity 2, while the arrow function you have defined has arity 1.

As per the source of [curryN](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/curryN.js), method is executed if the arity is 1.

**Solution**, replace `Number.parseInt` by `Number`, **it should work**, [working link](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?console.log%28ifElse%28%0A%20%20identity%2C%0A%20%20%28s%29%20%3D%3E%20Number.parseInt%28s%29%2C%0A%20%20always%281%29%0A%29%28%2733%27%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%20%22divider%22%20%29%0A%0Aconsole.log%28ifElse%28%0A%20%20identity%2C%0A%20%20Number%2C%20%0A%20%20always%281%29%0A%29%28%2733%27%29%29%3B%0A%20%0Aconsole.log%28%20%22-----------------End-------------%22%20%29%0A)

2. `Number.parseInt` is a *function reference* with its own `this` and `arguments` object, however *arrow functions* don't have their own arguments hence there is a [difference between how apply and call work on arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Invoked_through_call_or_apply)

Comment: Point 1 seems the only thing relevant.  I'm not sure what you're getting at in point 2, but `Number.parseFloat` would work as expected since it is a unary function, but it has the same structure as `Number.parseInt`

Comment: @ScottSauyet Only highlighting how both of them are different, and yes 2) is not relevant to the output.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from gurvinder372 gives the best solution.  (An alternative would be to wrap `Number.parseInt` in `R.unary`.)

The reason this happens, though, if you're interested, is that `ifElse` returns a curried function that has the arity of the largest arity of the three functions supplied to it (the predicate, ifTrue, and ifFalse.)  Since `parseInt` has arity 2, and not 1 or 0 like the others, the returned function has arity 2.

This behavior was [discussed recently](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2374) on the Ramda issues list.